# how to resolve the UIComponent was not found in action script

Tags: actionscript-3

am creating an action script  class MyCircle extends UIComponent.....some code

when i compile i get error
 as col: 28 Error: The definition of base class UIComponent was not found.

```
class MyCircle extends UIComponent
```

what i have to do
                           ^

Comment: Need more information here.  What environment are you building in?  Can you post more of the surrounding code?

Answer (score 2):

Add this at the beginning :

```
import mx.core.UIComponent;
```